# How to replace the JMeter file content with dynamic value

Tags: http, jmeter

I have a file and which has HTTP request content.In the content I want to place the dynamic value from CSV Config I have.If I copy the content in request data which is replacing with dynamic value otherwise it is not replacing the USERID 
value. Scenario 1 is working and Scenario 2 is not working.

```
---------CSV Data Set Config and which has Variable Name as USERID ---
USERID
000001
000002
000003
000004
000005
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Scenario 1: HTTP Content in Body Data of HTTP Request

```
---------------Body Data-----------------------------
    {
    "userID":"${USERID}",
    "idType":"SID"
    } 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Scenario 2: HTTP Request Content in File and File reference is in Body Data of HTTP Request

```
---------------Body Data-----------------------------
    ${__FileToString(C:\apache-jmeter-4.0bin\request-data-file.txt,,)}
-----------------------------------------------------

----request-data-file.txt File Content:--------------
    {
    "userID":"${USERID}",
    "idType":"SID"
    } 
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function into [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) function, this way JMeter will evaluate the nested variables and return their respective values.

The syntax would be something like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(C:\apache-jmeter-4.0bin\request-data-file.txt,,)})}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)